# Extjs4, filter store dynamically

Tags: extjs, filter, store

I fill out an array dynamically with a list of Ids:

```
var allChildNodeIDs = [];
Ext.getCmp('categoriesTreePanel').getRootNode().eachChild(function(Mynode){
        allChildNodeIDs.push(Mynode.data.idCategorie);
   });
```

Then I want to filter a store according to all Ids contained in the array. For example if the array contains two values, I want that my store will be filtered like so:

```
myStore.filterBy(function(record) {
            return (record.get('idCategorie') == allChildNodeIDs [1] && record.get('idCategorie') == allChildNodeIDs [2]);
        });
```

But the array is filled out dynamically, and I don't know his length!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the sorting function in your example would always return `false`. I assume what you want to do is accept all the record which category is present into the array (i.e. that ou meant to use `||` instead of `&&`).

You can use `Array`'s [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method.

Example:

```
myStore.filterBy(function(record) {
    return allChildNodeIDs.indexOf(record.get('idCategorie')) !== -1;
});
```